# Polymorphism:what is the real type of the called method?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

Can anyone explain the behaviour of this code , as I'm playing with polymorphism I came up with this code by coincidence, and I'm really confused with its behaviour:

```
public class Book
{
    public virtual void Method() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Book/ I am here in "+ GetType().Name);
    } 
} 
class Chapter : Book
{
    public new void Method() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Chapter/ I am here in "+ GetType().Name);
    }

    static void Main() 
    {
        Book myBook = new Chapter() ;
        myBook.Method();
    } 
}
```

The output from this program is

> Book/ I am here in Chapter

This means that the instance called the method within the book class but gets the type `chapter`. 
 Does `GetType()` method depend on the instance it called with, not the class it lies in?

Comment: There not much need for a method that returns the static type based on the call location, since you have that information more readily to hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `GetType()` gets the actual type from the object (instance) at runtime.

If you changed `public new void Method()`
to public `override void Method()` it would print out the other line.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.OBJECT.GETTYPE%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2CVERSION%3DV4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true):

> Return Value
>
> Type: System.Type
>
> The exact runtime type of the current instance.

Answer (score 1):

`new` destroys polymorphism. That's the whole point of `new`, in fact - hiding the virtual implementation.

If you want to change the implementation of a method in a derived type, you need to use `override` instead of `new`. This will ensure that the overriden method is called even if the correct type isn't known at compile time.